# Assembly Language Error

Tags: assembly

I have been attempting to debug my program, but it always seems to get caught up when I call my function. I get an error saying

> "Unhandled exception at 0x0018fed8 in windows32.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation."

I tried researching and what I gathered is that it is a stack error. Is there any other possibilities?

```
    .586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096     

.DATA           ; reserve storage for data
number1         WORD        ?
anArray         WORD        100 DUP (?)
count           WORD        ?
search          WORD        ?
prompt1         BYTE        "Enter a number or -1 to quit.", 0
prompt2         BYTE        "Enter a number to search for", 0
prompt3         BYTE        "Search for another number Y/N",0
inString        BYTE        40 DUP (?)
searchString    BYTE        16 DUP (?)
outMsgLabel     BYTE        "Search Result", 0
frontOut1       BYTE        6 DUP (?)
outMsg1         BYTE        " is element"
rearOut1        BYTE        6 DUP (?),0
frontOut2       BYTE        6 DUP (?)
outMsg2         BYTE        " is not in array",0

EXTERN          function1:PROC

.CODE           ; start of main program code
_MainProc       PROC
                lea         ebx, anArray
                mov         cx, count
moveThrough:    input       prompt1, inString, 40   ; read ASCII characters
                atow        inString                ; convert to integer
                cmp         ax,0                    ; check for -1
                jl          next
                mov         [ebx], eax              ; store in memory
                add         ebx,2                   ; move to next location in array
                inc         ecx
                cmp         ecx,50                  ; check to make sure array isn't over 50
                je          next
                jmp         moveThrough             ; jump to add more numbers


next:           lea         ebx, anArray            ; get address of array
                mov         count, cx
                input       prompt2, inString, 40   ; prompt for number to search for
                atow        inString
                mov         dx,ax
                mov         cx,count                ; prep cx to be the counter
                lea         eax, anArray
                push        eax
                push        edx
                push        ecx
                call        function1
                add         esp,6
                cmp         eax,0
                je          notThere
                jmp         equalTo

notThere:       wtoa        frontOut2, search
                output      outMsgLabel,frontOut2   ; output message
                jmp         searchAgain

equalTo:        wtoa        frontOut1, search
                wtoa        rearOut1, ax
                output      outMsgLabel,frontOut1   ; output message
                mov         cx,count
                jmp         searchAgain



searchAgain:    input       prompt3, searchString, 16 ; prompt for search again input
                cmp         searchString,"n"          ; check for n
                je          end1
                cmp         searchString,"N"          ; check forN
                je          end1
                jmp         next

end1:


                mov         eax, 0                  ; exit with return code 0
                ret
_MainProc       ENDP
                END                                 ; end of source code

.586
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE

;void function1(int count, int search, int array[])
;outputs whether the search is in the array
function1       PROC
                push        ebp         
                mov         ebp,esp
                push        ebx
                push        ecx
                push        edx
                push        esi
                mov         ecx,[ebp]
                mov         edx,[ebp+2]
                mov         esi,[ebp+4]

arraySearch:    mov         ax, dx                      
                cmp         [esi],ax                ; check if number is in array
                je          equalTo                 
                add         ebx,2                   ; move to next number in array
                loop        arraySearch             ; loop back to top

notThere:       pop         esi
                pop         edx
                pop         ecx
                pop         ebx
                mov         ax,0
                ret

equalTo:        pop         esi
                pop         edx
                pop         ecx
                pop         ebx
                inc         cx
                mov         ax,cx
                ret

                ret
function1       ENDP

END
```

Comment: What is this program supposed to do?

Comment: Enter an array of up to 50 numbers then search the array for the number. I had already made it without the function and it worked, but now I have to turn it into a function and I can't get the main program to call the function.

Comment: What makes `_MainProc` the main program?  Is it called from somewhere else?  It doesn't look like it though.  Maybe the linker is set to make that the start address?  If so, you need to establish the stack pointer (and, if it references to it were added, the frame pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why are you adding 6 to esp after your call to function1?  This is 32bit Assembly and the stack is DWORD aligned, you pushed 3 32bit registers so you should be adding 12 to esp after your call to function1.
2. In function1, you set up a stack frame with:

   push    ebp

   mov     ebp, esp

Where do you pop ebp and restore the stack pointer?  These 2 errors will mess your program up big time!

Oh, and that being said, the parameters to your function start at [ebp + 8] and for each parameter add 4 to that offset.
1st param = [ebp + 8]
2nd = [ebp + 12]
3rd = [ebp + 16]
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Does `atow` expect a NULL terminated string by any chance?  A `0xC0000005` is a memory error that can also be caused by writing to memory that is not yours, writing a multibyte value to an unaligned location (e.g, moving a 32-bit value to an odd memory address), etc.  It is not limited to stack related errors.

**Update**
Should the following line in `function` be adjusting `esi` instead of `ebx`?

```
            add         ebx,2                   ; move to next number in array
```

*I haven't read X86 for quite some time, so my memory of register interactions is a little fuzzy.*

**Update 2**
Does the `EXTERN` keyword tell the assembler to look in a different library?  `EXTERN` usually means *"look somewhere else for the symbol"*.  I honestly can say that I have never worked with anything other than single units in assembly.  I mostly see dis-assembled code these days.  The program could be jumping off in to space if it expects to be branching to somewhere non-local.  What assembler are you using?

Comment: No, It does not. I can get past that part when I debug step by step.

EDIT: Yes, it should be adding 2 to esi, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: How far do you get when debugging?  I'm not sure what happens if you use the same label more than once (e.g., `equalTo` and `notThere`) and a few other things.

Comment: I get to the line that says "call function1". That's when it throws the error.